# what is g++-mp-4.3?

Tags: g++, macports

MacPorts installs something called g++-mp-4.3?

Does the "mp" mean MacPorts, or is it something else?  I can't find any documentation anywhere...

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's GNU C++ as provided by MacPorts. The full form for GNU executables is `<name>[-<variant>][-<version>]`. The variant and version can be omitted to indicate that it is the primary executable with that name for the system.

Comment: Thanks. I thought it meant "multi-precision" or something useful like that. I wonder why they started adding mp at 4.3 but the previous versions didn't have it.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, 'mp' means MacPorts. g++-mp-4.3 is C++ compiler from GCC for MacPorts.